# How to mock third party imports to run unit tests

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test module which imports other modules which have an inner class. My setup is as follows:

filename: class_b.py

```
class B:

    class C:
        print("C")
```

Other class: class_a.py

```
import class_b

class A:

    def test(self):
        print('A')
```

Test driver:

```
import class_a

def test():
    a = class_a.A()
    a.test()

test()
```

Now when I run my tests, `print(c)` get executed first, even when I dont want it to get invoked. How do I control the execution of it. In my real app this line contains code for network calls and so unit tests are failing.

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: You may have over-reduced your code for the question. In this example code, the `print` line in nested class `C` it not in a method. So it's going to be invoked real-time as the class file is parsed, when you import it. Is this intentional? Does it match the behavior you're trying to mock? If so, why would you print (or invoke any behavior) in class C without putting it in a method?

Comment: @JimStewart yes, this is the current behavior which is needed. I am using pynamodb which is defining class Meta and all properties just under it. https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: @ReblochonMasque thanks. Updated my code.

Comment: You can go one level deeper and mock DynamoDB connection instead of your own code. Or you can use [`DynamoDBLocal`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html), although this would mean running a local DB instance.

Comment: Thing is, `print("C")` is executed on import, so unless you move the `import class_a` inside the test, with probably unloading the imports at the end of the test (so it doesn't interfere with others), or using `importlib` machinery, you won't be able to isolate the model code. All of this will make your tests unnecessary complicated. Better mock the underlying DB connection, returning some fake values.